# Taxonomy autocomplete is empty because of access control for anonymous users

Tags: ajax, taxonomy-terms

I am using [Finder](https://www.drupal.org/project/finder), a great module for autocomplete searches. I am using it for autocompleting results from a taxonomy vocabulary. The way Finder works is it uses views for the autocomplete results. My view is a simple HTML list of all the terms from the vocabulary.

The taxonomy vocabulary is restricted only to logged in users. This causes the autocomplete to return empty results. I changed access settings in the view, but that didn't help.

Can anyone suggest a way around this?

I could simply redirect from the vocabulary path, but I'm not sure it's a good solution, since the data really needs to be private. How safe is it to just redirect?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the access settings didn't help because Drupal filters out items that are not accessible by the user currently viewing the view.  There are a number of ways you can deal with this:

1. Use [Vocabulary Permissions Per Role](https://www.drupal.org/project/vppr) which gives finer grained control of taxonomies
2. Use Page Manager (part of [ctools](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools)) to override the taxonomy page either by redirecting somewhere else or making your own page in Page Manager using [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels).
3. As you suggest, use a redirection module (or Rules perhaps) to redirect users away from the page.  The data will be safe as long as the rule or redirection fires before anything is rendered.